# Sequelize - hasMany slow fetching one with many relations

Tags: sequelize.js

I have one entity with 5 `hasMany` on it.

```
@Table
class Book extends Model<Book> {
    @ForeignKey(() => Person)
    @Column
    authorId: number;

    @BelongsTo(() => Person)
    author: Person;
}

@Table
class Person extends Model<Person> {
    @HasMany(() => Book)
    writtenBooks: Book[];

    @HasMany(() => Car)
    cars: Car[];

    @HasMany(() => Cat)
    cats: Cat[];
}
```

When I load one person, it fetches the `hasMany` items with join.
The query inside mysql returns the result very fast, but sequelize takes time build the result set. and the CPU climbs.
I assume that this is because it handles a lot of duplicated data and need to build the correct resultset.

This is the query:

```
.findOn({where:{id}, include:['cats','cars','writtenBooks']});
```

is it possible to force the query to fetch by subqueirs in order to get accurate amount of rows in the result.
What are the options to speed it up?

Thanks

Comment: include your query....

Comment: @doublesharp - added thanks

Comment: Do you need to return any complex data for those records? How many results are returned? You can use `raw: true` for the results to not parse into Instances, and you can try setting `required: false` on the joins to make them LEFT JOINS. Otherwise you might need to profile to see what part is slow, could be the database needs indexes, more memory, etc

Comment: @doublesharp `raw: true` made the hasOne faster and im using it. when it comes to has many, `raw: true` has no effect and  `required: false` has no effect as well. I dont mind flattening the result, but it does not help for "hasMany"